# Setting TestNG test case result as PASS/FAIL as per my requirement

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have one requirement, I need to read the test data from the excel sheet and after the test case execution I need to write in to excel sheet as PASS/Fail/ Skip.

I have used TestNG framework,Below are sample code/approach Which I have followed but no luck I am always getting result as 1(SUCCESS),even test case fail also.Please some body help me

```
@AfterSuite
public void write(){
    int result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getStatus();
    if(ITestResult.FAILURE == result){
        System.out.println("AFTER METHOD IN FAILURE:: "+result);
    }else if(ITestResult.SUCCESS == result){
        System.out.println("AFTER METHOD IN SUCCESS:: "+result);
    }
    else if(ITestResult.SKIP == result){
        System.out.println("AFTER METHOD IN SKIP :: "+result);
    }
Output : AFTER METHOD IN SUCCESS:: 1
```

Comment: The issue seems to be in the function which is passing the status to this method.

Comment: Hello log_file, do you have any idea about resolving the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different approach, this worked for me

```
@AfterMethod
public void writeResult(ITestResult result)
{
    try
    {
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {

            //Do your excel writing stuff here
        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            takeScreenshot(dateTimeStamp,driver,methodName);
            System.out.println("Log Message:: @AfterMethod: Method-"+methodName+"- has Failed");
            //Do your excel writing stuff here

        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            System.out.println("Log Message::@AfterMethod: Method-"+methodName+"- has Skipped");

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("\nLog Message::@AfterMethod: Exception caught");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can alter your approach to include a configuration method using @AfterMethod, then you can pass in a paramater for ITestResult, which holds the results for the most recently completed test method.  That class has a method called getStatus() that will give you the status of that test.

Here's an example of how to use this:

```
@AfterMethod
public void fetchMostRecentTestResult(ITestResult result) {

    int status = result.getStatus();

    switch (status) {
        case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
            //do something
            break;
        case ITestResult.FAILURE:
            //do something else
            break;
        case ITestResult.SKIP:
            //and something else
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid status");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use Selenium+jxl+TestNG framework combination and it is possible using 
FileInputStream+FileOutputStream classes,like below example

Example:

```
public class Excelutility {

    public String Testcase;
    public WritableSheet writablesh;
    public WritableWorkbook workbookcopy;

@BeforeTest
public void queryParameterization() throws BiffException,IOException,RowsExceededException,WriteException, InterruptedException{

FileInputStream testfile = new FileInputStream("E:\\AppiumTutorials\\Selenium_Practice\\SeleniumYoutube\\Testdata\\TestData.xls");
//Now get Workbook
Workbook wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(testfile);
//Now get Workbook Sheet
Sheet sheets = wbook.getSheet("Query_data");
int Norows = sheets.getRows();
//Read rows and columns and save it in String Two dimensional array
String inputdata[][] = new String[sheets.getRows()][sheets.getColumns()];
System.out.println("Number of rows present in TestData xls file is -"+Norows);

//For writing the data into excel we will use FileoutputStream class
FileOutputStream testoutput = new FileOutputStream("E:\\AppiumTutorials\\Selenium_Practice\\SeleniumYoutube\\Testdata\\TestData_results.xls");
System.out.println("creating file one");
//To Create writable workbook
workbookcopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(testoutput);
System.out.println("creating file 2");
//To Create Writable sheet in Writable workbook
writablesh = workbookcopy.createSheet("Query_data",0);
System.out.println("creating file 3");

//Using for loop to write all the data to new sheet
    for(int i=0;i<sheets.getRows();i++)
       {
        for(int k=0;k<sheets.getColumns();k++)
        {
         inputdata[i][k] = sheets.getCell(k, i).getContents();
         Label l = new Label(k, i, inputdata[i][k]);
         Label l2 = new Label(4,0,"Results");            
         writablesh.addCell(l);
         writablesh.addCell(l2);
        }
       }            
    }

@AfterTest
public void writeexcels(){
    try {
        workbookcopy.write();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        workbookcopy.close();
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Call this utility into another class using extends keyword.

Please read for more here [How to write Test Case pass/fail using selenium](https://youtu.be/2KQVXl0QDNU)